# Is redshift acting on pulses from pulsars and how it changes the diffraction of the pulse and so its brightness?

Tags: space-expansion, diffraction, photon-emission, redshift, pulsars

Is redshift acting on pulses from pulsars and how it changes the diffraction of the pulse and so its brightness? As far as I know the diffraction becomes higher while wavelength increases as moving away from the source.